# Parks around Manado Sulawesi for viewing plants and animals

Tags: online-resources, indonesia, nature-and-wildlife

What is available around Manado for seeing plants and animals?

I was focusing on Bogani but that was because I thought I read somewhere that it had a better assortment, however I am not sure, I notice most people go to closer national parks (not sure if they are just better known, picked because they are closer, or picked because they are better)

Do you know where I can find a site with more information about the parks or at least a list with their names and general locations?

Comment: Hi Dan, people here don't like words like "recommended" because it could be read as asking for opinion polls, and a few people have started voting to close - but it's clear from the question body that you're asking about parks that have varied selections of plants and animals so I've edited the title. If there are any particular sorts of plants and animals you're looking to see, that might help. Also I'd suggest asking about sampling endemic fruits as a separate question since that'll have different answers to your question about parks

Comment: "what is available" is not "build me an itinerary." It is a question with a concrete answer. This should be reopened.

Comment: My question is actually quantifiable since one could say "this park has X species of mammals Y species of birds...." and compare things that way, or by trail area, biomes included....  Likewise one could discuss how intact the parks are (some parks get raided by illegal logging...).  So I don't really see how that is "personal preference".

Answer (score 1):

[TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g297721-Activities-c57-Manado_North_Sulawesi_Sulawesi.html) has a dozen entries under "Nature & Parks in Manado" some of which include a map and/or an address.

I doubt they are all quite what you are looking for but wonder whether just one [Tangkoko Research Station](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g297721-d10629203-Reviews-Tangkoko_Research_Station-Manado_North_Sulawesi_Sulawesi.html#review_411319412) might be sufficient. On the northern tip of Sulawesi, so about two hours northeast of Manado rather than about four hours southwest. [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tangkoko_National_Park) mentions:

> ... a variety of hardwood trees and unusual plant life. The animal life is also quite varied, and one can often view Tarsius tarsier(world's smallest primate), black tailless monkeys, Maleo Birds, wild pigs and kuskus (marsupial family)

and

> **Flora and fauna**
>
> Tangkoko Nature Reserve protects at least 127 mammal, 233 bird and 104
>   reptile and amphibian species. Of these 79 mammal, 103 bird and 29
>   reptile and amphibian species are endemic to the island.
>
> Threatened mammals include the Celebes crested macaque, of which about
>   5,500 remain on the island, the Sulawesi bear cuscus and Sulawesi
>   dwarf cuscus.

[image: Pig]
*Babyrousa celebensis* image courtesy Masteraah at German Wikipedia

For mammals they mention: Crested Black Macaque (*Macaca nigra*), Spectral Tarsier (*Tarsius spectrum*), Bear Cuscus (*Ailurops ursinus*), Sulawesi Dwarf Cuscus (*Strigocuscus celebensis*), Bats (the commonest Rousette (*Rousettus celebensis*) and Lesser Dog-faced Fruit Bat (*Cynopterus brachyotis*) but the island is home to 20 other species, including many rare and peculiar forms about which little is known Tangkoko), Northern Dwarf Squirrel (*Prosciurillus murinus*) and Pale Dwarf Squirrel (*Prosciurillus leucomus*), Sulawesi Forest Pig (*Sus celebensis*), Babirusa (*Babyrousa babyrussa*), and Timor Deer (*Cervus timorensis*).